# Join wireless network automatically without plain-text passphrase

Tags: macos

I'd like to automate the process of joining a wireless network if that network becomes disconnected on a Mac running macOS 10.14 Mojave, using keychain credentials if possible.

The situation is: this is a remote machine that sometimes becomes disconnected from the wireless network if the network goes down. When this happens the machine needs to be physically accessed and told to connect to the proper SSID.